JNI Not compatible for apple ARM Arch
I've been using a certain dependency to implement event listeners for mouse and keyboard tracking on Windows and Mac systems with Intel chips. However, upon transitioning to a Mac with an M1 chip (ARM architecture - Apple Silicon chip), I encounter an exception. Could you suggest an alternative library suitable for this situation?
GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(this);
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseMotionListener(this);
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseWheelListener(this);

   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
      <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

Dependency which is working fine for Intel chip
Apr 01, 2024 11:26:16 PM org.jnativehook.DefaultLibraryLocator getLibraries
SEVERE: Unable to extract the native library /org/jnativehook/lib/darwin/unsupported/libJNativeHook.dylib!


Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.Integer org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.getAutoRepeatRate()'
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.getAutoRepeatRate(Native Method)
    at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.staffViz.controllers.main_controllers.RunningTrackerModuleController.itemStateChanged(RunningTrackerModuleController.java:177)
    at com.staffViz.controllers.main_controllers.RunningTrackerModuleController.initialize(RunningTrackerModuleController.java:121)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2670)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at com.staffViz.controllers.main_controllers.ProjectMainScreenController.startTracker(ProjectMainScreenController.java:1362)
    at com.staffViz.listViewCell.TaskCell.startTracker(TaskCell.java:325)
    at com.staffViz.listViewCell.TaskCell.lambda$updateItem$7(TaskCell.java:168)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3688)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3993)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)


More recent versions support aarch64

its supports 10-10.5 os version not comaptible for 14 ios
https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook
you will see the below details in the link:
Software and Hardware Requirements
Java 1.8 - 17
256 MB of RAM
Apple OS X 10.5 - 10.15
amd64, aarch64
Enable Access for Assistive Devices
Windows 2000 - 10
i586, amd64, arm7

or can you me more details?

What do you mean by ios 14? IPhones are not compatible with Java. Not sure why would mention the IPhone operating system.

By the way, JNI is supplanted by Foreign Function & Memory API in Java 22+. See JEP 454

@aled Sorry, I want  to write macos 14

Native code needs to be compiled for the specific architecture and operating system where it will be executed. You can not just use an Intel library in an ARM CPU. You need to get the appropriate build from the provider, or if you have the source build it yourself.
JNativeHook 2.1.0 is too old and didn't include macOS (Darwin) with ARM as a target. Apple M1 chip based computers were not even released at that time.
You need to update to the current release, 2.2.2 at this time, which supports the Darwin/aarch64 target. The distribution includes the appropriate version of the native library.

@basilBorque I am using this updated library but after sometime key pressing it's not working.

Then the issue from your question is solved, right?

yes, resolved. Thank you!
